# Filter, print to PDF and save

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I want to create a code that will do the following.

From pivot table filter based on a "project number" 0-100 for example. Then print the filtered data to pdf. Then move onto the next project number and repeat.

The issue I'm coming up against is the project numbers are variable each week. so it may only be 1,10,12,14 in week one but then 2,32,42,100 in the following week.

Any suggestion's on this would be great, I've pasted the beginning of what I've got so far but I don't think it's anywhere near correct.

```
Sub PDF_printer()
'
' PDF_printer Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Approved (Y)?"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Approved (Y)?")
        .PivotItems("Y").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Contract Simple"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Contract Simple")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("6").Visible = False
End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

I know this has no print function yet, that bit I think I can do.

Comment: The project numbers in discussion can be found in `PivotFields("Contract Simple")`? If yes, are there some other project numbers then the ones needed to be processed?

Comment: Only some times. if there is no data for a project in the particular week it will not be in PivotFields("Contract Simple") but I need the code to look for it and if It cant find it move on. if that makes sense?

Comment: Not really... Based on what algorithm the code would know which of the existing projects mus be processed and which to be skipped?

Comment: In my data that fills the table only certain project numbers would be filled in if they were used that week. any project numbers that were not used would not come up in the filter.

Comment: But, where and when this "filter" will be applied? Not any filtering criteria is connected to the project number?